# Using SUM on nvarchar field

Tags: sql

Is it possible to use SUM function in a SQL query on a field that has been set as nvarchar but only contains numbers?

Comment: Change the column type to be the correct type and you won't have such issues.

Comment: Sometimes (such as if you're working with a third-party schema), such changes aren't always possible.

Comment: @Oded - I wish I could downvote your comment. You are assuming so many things about the OP. He may not have any control over the DB. There may be other reasoning why the column is nvarchar (like some API reading the DB can only read text columns, or something like that). Unhelpful comments that look down on the asker are not the SO spirit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is possible by casting:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(NVarcharCol as int))
```

However, this will throw an exception is 1 or more records cannot be `CAST` to an `int`.

If your column is only ever going to have numerical values, I would recommend changing the data type to int to save future problems.

If you are not able to change the data type, then the following `WHERE` clause would prevent exceptions from being thrown:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC([NVarcharCol])=1
```

Comment: This solution could extended to exclude those values which are not numeric in the where clause thus preventing the type cast error in the first place. Or within the code you could check to see if any non-numeric values exist first and handle them before attempting the query. this overhead comes at a cost each time due to the field not being int to start with.

Comment: @xQbert - Cheers I've included the `WHERE` clause option in my answer

Comment: Was a good answer to begin with, I thought there may be some value to the OP with the comment.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum (cast (myFiled as int)) from myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You Need Casting,Try this

```
SUM(COALESCE(CoumnName, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the varchar to numeric type before using SUM on it, instead you'll have an error:

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

If it contains only numeric data - then what is the point of storing the data in varchar?

Comment: This is a historical database that I have picked up and need to run queries on, the data type was set up years ago.

Answer (score 0):

use SUM(COALESCE(CoumnName, 0))
I recommend ,You should change data type to number.Its good practice.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add two nvarchar columns. 
column TestTotal (nvarchar), column TestFailed (nvarchar), column TestPassed (nvarchar)

```
UPDATE [your_db].[dbo].[your_table] 
SET your_table.TestTotal = Convert(nvarchar, cast (your_table.TestFailed as int) + cast (your_table.TestPassed as int))
WHERE TestTotal='your_condition';
```