# How to cast nvarchar to integer?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database I'm running queries on where I cannot change the schema.  I am in my second year of database management.  We have not touched much on writing actual SQL as opposed to just using the GUI to create our queries and manage our DB's.

I have a population attribute that I need to run SUM on but the population is datatype ncharvar.  I need to cast it to int.

I don't know how to do that in SQL though!  Can someone please show me?  I've been fiddling with it for awhile and I'm out of ideas. I'm very unfamiliar with SQL (as simple as it looks) and this would be helpful.

```
SELECT dbo_City.CityName, Sum(dbo_City.Population) AS SumOfPopulation
FROM dbo_City
GROUP BY dbo_City.CityName
ORDER BY dbo_City.CityName, Sum(dbo_City.Population);
```

I need to find what cities have populations between 189,999 and 200,000, which is a very simple query.  I'm grouping by city and using the sum of the population.  I'm not sure where to insert the 189,999-200,000 figure in the query but I can figure that out later.  Right now I'm stuck on casting the ncharvar Population field to an Int so I can run this query!

I found the answer here:

[Using SUM on nvarchar field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788211/using-sum-on-nvarchar-field)

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(NVarcharCol as int))
```

But I'm not sure how to execute this solution.  Specifically, I'm not sure where to insert this code in the above provided SQL, and I don't understand why the nvarchar is called nvarchar**col**.

Comment: And I believe nvarcharcol is meant to be a placeholder for the name of the column to be cast as int from nvarchar. Gotta love examples that don't fully explain the why along with the how.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's in Access, so is the ms-access tag okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

Syntax for CAST:
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )

Your solution should look something like this:

```
SELECT c.CityName, CAST(c.Population AS INT) AS SumOfPopulation
FROM dbo_City AS c
WHERE ISNUMERIC(c.Population) = 1 AND CAST(c.Population AS INT) BETWEEN 189999 AND 200000
ORDER BY c.CityName, CAST(c.Population AS INT)
```

You shouldn't need the sum function unless you want to know the total population of the table, which would be more useful if it was a table of countries, cities, and city populations, unless this particular city table is broken down further (such as with individual zip codes?). In that case, the below would be the preference:

```
SELECT c.CityName, SUM(CAST(c.Population AS INT)) AS SumOfPopulation
FROM dbo_City AS c
WHERE ISNUMERIC(c.Population) = 1
GROUP BY c.CityName
HAVING SUM(CAST(c.Population AS INT)) BETWEEN 189999 AND 200000
ORDER BY c.CityName, SUM(CAST(c.Population AS INT))
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

-C§

Edit: Integrated the "fail safe" from your linked syntax, which should stop that error coming up. It adds a filter to the column to only process those that are able to be cast to a numeric type without extra processing (such as removing the comma as in vkp's response).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help!  It absolutely points me in the right direction and I appreciate you providing the source of MSDN as a solution for finding proper SQL syntax.

You're right, sum would be unnecessary.  I don't know why I was trying sum!  I'm hung up on casting.

I ran your first provided block of code and I received an error: **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(Population AS INT)'.**

Comment: @fischbs It's entirely possible that it's requiring the table to be referenced with the column name. I've changed the response to reflect an alias of `c` for the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help CSS. I feel foolish for having went with Sum and getting hung up on an issue that was entirely unnecessary, since I don't even need to run Sum in the query, however this has been a good learning experience and I appreciate the (very swiftly!) provided answers. For what it is worth, I'm still recieving the same error as before even with your new changes. If you want to keep working on it that's fine, but considering I just needed to group by CityName where Population is between 189999 and 200000, further assistance is unnecessary, save for your own curiosity about the error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I had temperatures (temp) stored as nvarchar. I wanted to filter out all temperatures under 50F. Unfortunately,
WHERE (temp > '5')
would include temperatures that started with a - sign (-5, -6, ...); even worse, I discovered that temperatures over 100F were also getting discarded.

SOLUTION:
WHERE (CAST (temp as SMALLINT) > '50')

I know this doesn't "directly" answer your question but for the life of me I couldnt find a specific answer to my problem anywhere on the web.  I thought it would be lame to answer my own question, so I wanted to add that my discovery to your answer.